# Will Haskell Platform be available in 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, haskell

I've been waiting for a couple years to be able to do an

```bsh
apt-get install haskell-platform
```

on Ubuntu. Will a haskell platform-package be available on Ubuntu 10.10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's already [packaged](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/haskell-platform/) and released in `maverick` (the development branch of Ubuntu):

```
$ rmadison haskell-platform
haskell-platform | 2010.1.0.0.1 | maverick/universe | source, all
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/haskell-platform